# SQL: how to write a query to find out which columns contain a certain value

Tags: sql

the data has over 50 columns, there is one or multiple columns which contain a value, say "US". and i want to find out the columns names. I can check column one by one, but it is time consuming. Anyone has an efficient way to do it? thank you so much!

Comment: This is a sign that your database is badly designed.  If you need to search across columns, then you should have had a separate table with multiple rows instead.  It is not impossible, using ugly tricks with `information_schema`, but it's not pretty.  Are you doing this from a program?

Comment: What type of database and version?  ms sql server 2017, mysql 8, postgresql 14, oracle 11g,... The method might be different depending on the RDBMS.

Comment: If you're looking for a complete match try `where 'US' in (col1, col2, col3, ..., col50)` Of courses that's just shorthand for a bunch of `or` conditions.